# EmberJS - Loading model in Route and user experience

Tags: ember.js

I load my model in Route's "model" hook. The route does not transition until the model data is fetched.

Browser remains in old route until the data comes in, resulting in bad user experience.

What is the best practice to load model in Ember 2.0 so that we can present atleast the new template to user without data for better user experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember provides a 'loading' route for you while your model for any route is loading. You could copy your new template, create a `loading.hbs` template for the new route, and paste it in there so it will show while the model hook resolves the model.

This is well documented in the Ember Guides: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/